# Is it appropriate to declare a non-static constant data member inside a class while coding?

Tags: c++, constants, datamember, data-members

data member inside a class can be const but only if its static.
otherwise we need to have a constructor to initialize a constant inside a class.

```
can we declare a const data member inside a class? //this was an interview question
```

It seems to me that we can, but is it appropriate for a programmer to declare a constant inside a class.

please give some explanation/reasons, why we can or cannot do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course you can :

```
struct A
{
    A() : a(5)
    {
    }
    const int a;
};

int main()
{
   A a;
}
```

This means that the data member a, inside struct A is not going to change.

Comment: Is it good programming practice to do so(I mean is there any other better way) and also what if the data member is a private.

Comment: @munish If this data member shouldn't change during the lifetime of objects of this type, then feel free to declare it const. Look up the "const correctness" on google

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : You can have a non-static `const` member inside a class.

As you still need to assign it a value, the only place where you're allowed to is in the initialization list.

And, well, it's always a good reason to do it if your member is really constant. I mean, const-correctness is mainly an optional tool to help better coding, so use it if you want, you'll thank yourself later. And if you don't use it... well it doesn't really matter!

Answer (score 1):

sure if you have some constants you want to use in your class, and belong to a class.

For example, lets say you have some data type with a unique ID, the ID identifies the object an therefor will never change:

```
class myData {
   cont int ID;
   myData(int newID) : ID(newID) {}
}
```